# c++ how to overwrite method in subclass

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, virtual, function-declaration

I have some code I'm trying to get to work, I'm open to other suggestions on how to do this. Basically, I have some base class that I want a bunch of subclasses to inherit. I then have a function that needs to call the subclass version of this method.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//my base class
class BaseClass {
    public:
    void myMethod(){
        std::cout  << "Base class?" << std::endl;
    }
};

/my subclass
class SubClass1: public BaseClass{
    public:

    void myMethod(){
        std::cout << "Subclass?" << std::endl;
    }
};

//method that I want to call SubClass.myMethod(). I cannot declare this as
//SubClass1 because there will be multiple of these.

void call_method(BaseClass object){
    return object.myMethod();
}


int main()
{
    BaseClass bc;
    SubClass1 sb1;

    //works how I expect it to
    sb1.myMethod();
    //I want this to also print "Subclass?"
    //but it prints "Base class?".
    call_method(sb1);



    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You're going to need to use polymorphism to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the member function in the base class as virtual. For example

```
virtual void myMethod() const {
    std::cout  << "Base class?" << std::endl;
}
```

And in the derived class to override it

```
void myMethod() const override {
    std::cout << "Subclass?" << std::endl;
}
```

And the function `call_method` must have a parameter that represents a reference to base class object

```
void call_method( const BaseClass &object){
    object.myMethod();
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you print **override**  in bold face. Because the OP has misspelled ot as ***overwrite***, and that might lead him to future misunderstandings.

Comment: Wasn't a misspell I just didn't know about that keyword, but thanks for the point.

Comment: For future reference, the `const` addition is not necessary. But you MUST pass by reference.

Comment: @Chris I don't judge why you misspelled a word. You might or might not know. But now I know you'll remember it.

Comment: The key point is to mark the **overridable** function as **virtual** in the topmost base class. Subsequent uses of **override** keyword are optional but also recommended, so that if the base class has not declared the function **virtual**, compiler stops.